# I using ffmpeg to live stream a hd video to rtmp server of facebook but when see it only show 360 quality

Tags: facebook, ffmpeg

This is my ffmpeg code :

```
'ffmpeg -i "{}"  ' \
      '-vf "zoompan=z=\'min(max(zoom,pzoom)+0.0015,2)\':d=1:x=\'iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)\':y=\'ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)\'" ' \
      '-vcodec libx264 ' \
      '-preset veryfast ' \
      '-maxrate 2932k ' \
      '-bufsize 2500k ' \
      '-vf "format=yuv420p" ' \
      '-g 60 ' \
      '-acodec libmp3lame ' \
      '-b:a 198k ' \
      '-ar 44100 ' \
      '-s 1280x720 ' \
      '-f flv "{}"
```

I have wasted 2 day for this problem. Thanks for reading !

Comment: What's the input resolution?

Comment: 720 HD video . I downloaded it from youtube

Comment: When your zoom is 2x, zoompan will crop a 640x360 window from the input. Your video should be natively at least 2560x1440 to maintain true 720p quality at all times.

Comment: If i don't zoom 2x . It still keep quality ?

Comment: Without zoompan, you can keep source quality.